# Routing for .js URL in ASP.Net MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Near the bottom of my routing registration, if a URL has a `.js` extension, I'd like to handle it with a particular controller (most .js content is served statically, but some is special and needs to be served via a controller). However, the following route is being skipped, and the catch-all route is handling the request.

```
routes.MapRoute("ContentScript", "{script}.js",
   new { controller = "Content", action = "Script" },
   new[] { "NameSpace.Controllers" }
);
```

What is the right way to do this?

In the route directly after that one every remaining request is routed like so (and this works *and* catches the .js files), so the issue is not in any part but the `url` parameter):

```
routes.MapRoute("ContentScript", "{*path}",
   new { controller = "Content", action = "Index" },
   new[] { "NameSpace.Controllers" }
);
```

I also tried the following, without success:

```
routes.MapRoute("ContentScript", "{*script}",
   new { controller = "Content", action = "Script" },
   new { script = new RegexConstraint("\\.js$") },
   new[] { "NameSpace.Controllers" }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an `IgnoreRoute` that I was unaware of (the RouteRegistry.cs file is 1,469 lines long... I have not studied it in its entirety, yet). js files are being handled in managed code--they were just being taken out by this before my route could handle the request.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*path}",
   new { path = new RegexConstraint(@"[^?]*\.(gif|jpe?g|png|ico|js|swf|css|txt|html?|xml|pdf)") }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add handler to the web.config so it can handle it ...
some thing like that :

```
<system.webserver>
    <handlers>
    <add name="scripts" path="*.js" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webserver>
```

[stackoverflow link #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16949425/2134482)

[stackoverflow link #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7138267/2134482)

Comment: The next route handles the .js file so this answer is incorrect.