# Sitecore: how to bypass MVC routing to allow direct access to a file/folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a Sitecore C# MVC/.Net 4.5 application.
I have a Javascript file that needs to be accessed by external sources.

As it is not part of any route, I get a 404 if I try to access it directly, even with the file existing.

How can I allow external access to this file?

Comment: so you have a javascript file which is accessed by a url for example right? and you want to add it to your views? or for example you want to download the file?

Comment: I currently cannot access it, I am getting a 404 because - I assume - there is no route that encompasses its path. I want to be able to access it, with a standard HTTP GET, in this case to include it in a page.

Comment: By default, files are served by the webserver and this logic happens before  ASP.NET is even called. This sounds more like a web server problem than one for MVC - what web server are you using?

Comment: The common thing to do is place it under `/Scripts`, or else perhaps `/Content`. I have never seen that fail.

Comment: I should have probably mentioned that this is a Sitecore application. I have edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: But then, Sitecore is an application not a web server, so we are back to square one.

Answer (score 2):

By default you should be able to access those files.
Check here.

[Why CSS and JS files bypass Asp.Net MVC routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948933/why-css-and-js-files-bypass-asp-net-mvc-routes)

If not then you might have (or someone) altered the "**Handlers**" Section of your web.config.

Or have the setting added, which routes all static files from the mvc pipeline.

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```